# How can I type hint a variable that might contain a literal class

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm adding some type hints to a stub of `vertica_python`. One of the functions internally accepts the following parameter (`cursor_type`):

```py
def row_formatter(self, row_data):
    if self.cursor_type is None:
        return self.format_row_as_array(row_data)
    elif self.cursor_type in (list, 'list'):
        return self.format_row_as_array(row_data)
    elif self.cursor_type in (dict, 'dict'):
        return self.format_row_as_dict(row_data)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unrecognized cursor_type: {0}'.format(self.cursor_type))
```

So this function expects 'list', 'dict', the **type** list or **type** dict. I would like to use Optional[Literal[list, dict, 'list', 'dict']], but this is not supported:

```
Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type hint it as `Union[None, Type[list], Type[dict], Literal["list", "dict"]]`

(import Union and Type from typing)

Just watch out, as this would also accept a subclass of list or dict

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. For some reason though, it still doesn't work. Pyright still complains with `Expected type arguments for generic class "list"`, even though it is wrapped by Type[].

Comment: I am having some trouble replicating this message. Are you using Pyright on Visual Studio Code? Also, which python version are you using?

Comment: Could you please also show the line in which you are using the type hint? Thanks!

Comment: A minimal example that already throws this error for me is this :

```python
from typing import Type

def x(y: Type[list]):
    return y
```

Also note that `Return type, "Type[list[Unknown]]", is partially unknown` also shows up.

The actual line I'm using it in looks like this:

```python
def cursor(self, cursor_type: Union[None, Literal['list', 'dict'], Type[list], Type[dict]]=...) -> Cursor:
    ...
```

Yes it's pyright in VSCode that is throwing these errors. I'm using python 3.8.10,

Comment: Thank you. I think that I understand what is going on. In your Pyright settings (Extensions > Pyright > Gear icon > Extension Settings), I believe that you may have "Type Checking Mode" set to strict. This is not necessarily a bad thing — it really depends on what you want. If you do want to adhere to these very strict rules, that's fine. Pyright, for you, is complaining that you do not specify which type of list it can be (eg. `List[int]`). A workaround is to change it to `List[Any]` and `Dict[Any, Any]` (`List` and `Dict` from typing)

Comment: I see. I was aware of this but was hoping for a workaround to specify that I really do just mean the literal class, without compromising on the strictness. But thank you for explaining how it works!

Comment: After some experimenting, I now realized that your workaround is actually exactly what I am looking for. Using `Type[list[Any]]` doesn't compromise on any strictness and models the behavior I want.